# Function does not seem to be executing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well... the tittle says it. Here, I leave you the link.
I lost nearly 4 hours trying to make it work!

I want to add rows to the table, when I click the button. But it does not seem to do anything at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/QqMsX/24/

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
 <tr>
     <th>Relation</th>
     <th>Column1</th>
     <th>Column2</th>
     <th>Column3</th>
     <th>Column4</th>
     <th>Column5</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody id = 'FamilyTable'>                          
    </tbody>
</table>                            

<button onclick ="AddRow()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

And the JavaScript Code.

```
function AddRow() 
{
    var Row = '<tr>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '<td>Data</td>'.
               '</tr>'; 

    $(Row).appendTo("#FamilyTable");    
}
```

Comment: To concatenate strings in JavaScript you have to use the + operator.

Comment: Moreover, you have to include jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, i got it, thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string concatenation character in Javascript is `+`, not `.`. Also note that your original fiddle did not include jQuery. Try this:

```
function AddRow() {
    var row = '<tr>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '<td>Data</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $(row).appendTo("#FamilyTable");
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqMsX/25/)

A better alternative would be to attach your events using Javascript to avoid the outdated `on*` attributes. Something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '<td>Data</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        $(row).appendTo("#FamilyTable");
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqMsX/28/)

Comment: And that's what happens when you don't stop working. Thank you sir!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @LeandroAlbertoGamarra you should mark Rory's answer as accepted then, so that anyone that stumbles upon this in the future knows that it solved your problem and may potentially solve theirs!

Comment: That look's clean enough. I like it.